# C: How to extract the doctype of a HTML page

Tags: html, c

I need to extract the ***doctype of a HTML page*** which may be XHTML, HTML html or WML, using C or C++. 
I will be giving the input as a HTML file or as an array.

if html pages does't contain  header then result should be in with respect to page like if it is html result = html or if it is xhtml result = xhtml....

Comment: It should give the what?

Comment: if  html pages does't contain <!doctype> header then  result should be in with respect to page like if it is html result = html or if it is xhtml result = xhtml....

Comment: What do you mean by 'give the res'? Normally 'res' is short for 'resolution' but I dont see how that can apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like two distinct questions:

1) how to simply grab the "doctype" declaration from an html page, for which I was going to suggest something simple like:

```
char doctype[1024];

void
get_doctype(char *html_page)
{
  sscanf(html_page, "<!DOCTYPE %1024s>", doctype);
}
```

Then perhaps match against known `doctype` strings to get an enumerated value.

But you're also asking 2) how to detect the type of a page with no doctype declaration.  That's harder, and there may be multiple correct answers for each page.  I would suggest outsourcing to a library like [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).  It has functions to validate input streams as certain types of documents.

Comment: hi good ans , **<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">** in this i want result as ***XHTML 1.0 Transitional*** if not result should be xhtml and even same for html sites also